# What is a active wallet vs inactive

Tags: gas, cpp-ethereum

In Apr. empower had an airdrop that they said only wallets that had .1 ETH. would get it. Was that the customary requirement in Jan when the crypto blockchain was jammed?. And wasn't that lowered to .01 by most exchanges by Feb? 
I suspect they were using old rates from Jan. They made everyone has .1 ETH due to their ineptness I figure. 
Is there a chart or data that shows what was customary at different times?

Answer (score 1):

Airdrops are completely up to the company putting them on. They can choose to distribute their token to someone holding 100 ETH, 1 ETH, 0.00001 ETH, etc. There is no "customary" airdrop usage statistics.

In terms of the blockchain being jammed, the only thing to consider is how many transactions are going to take place and how much are you willing to spend. If there is no traffic on the network, you can airdrop tokens to thousands of users for very little money (gas) (

By choosing to send to only accounts that have at least 1 ETH in them, you are eliminating a decent chunk of accounts from receiving an airdrop, saving you some money.

Comment: I guess empowr choose .1 to eliminate the poorest? I still think they think it is the amount most exchanges use as min. That is where I said customary min.